# Reading a cell value as a str in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to read a numeric cell value as a str rather than a float, but as far as I can see the API doesn't allow for this, is there something I'm missing?

The reason for this is the cell value is currency based, and as such I want to convert use it as a decimal not a float.

Alternatively, is there a way to get openpyxl to read the value directly as a decimal?

Comment: Why can't you just do **a = str(ws['A1'].value)**. If its a float with [redundant] leading/trailing zeros it would have to be saved as string (text) in order to stop Excel from removing these redundant zeros, in which case it'd be read as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel uses IEEE 754 binary64 float format internally. Inside an xlsx file, sheet XMLs contain ordinary float string representations, like so:

```xml
<c r="M11" s="592">
  <f>+K11*L11</f>
  <v>-3.6749999999999998</v>
</c>
```

Parsing this string as a float restores all accessible information perfectly. That said, float operations inside Excel lose accuracy, and there is no way to recover that precision without re-evaluating cell values or consulting external sources of data.